# Tableau Calculated Field to Display Placement in Sort Order

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am making a dashboard to rank the performance of employees based on around 20 metrics. I am wondering if I can create a calculated field that will output the placement they have in a descending sort of that metric.

For example, if they are 13th out of 20 employees based on accuracy, the field would output 13.

Is this possible?

Thank you,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just looking for the rank function: `rank([metricname])`, assuming that `metricname` is the result of an aggregation.  If not, wrap `[metricname]` in whatever function is applicable (i.e. sum, max, etc)

By default, `rank()` works in descending order, although this can be changed by passing in the `asc` argument after the expression.

**To make this dynamic:**
Create a parameter that contains all of your metric names, along with a metric that says `IF [parametername] = "metric1" then [metric1] ELSEIF [parametername] = "metric2" then [metric2] END` and use that as the argument within the call to `rank()`

Here's an article that explains this very well:
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/parameterized-measure